# Bloquear email já existente no jquery.validate

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário de cadastro que uso o plugin jquery.validate.js http://jqueryvalidation.org. pesquisei mas não achei uma maneira de retornar um erro quando o cliente insere um email já válido. qual a melhor alternativa para resolver meu problema?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Dá pra criar validações e mensagens customizadas. Como é essa verificação? Ajax ?

Comment: Poderia ser, só que quero usando o mesmo plugin, e aproveitar a mesma estrutura de mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 3):

O Validator tem uma propriedade chamada [`remote`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method) que pode usada no seu caso:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          email: function() {
            return $("#email").val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

O resultado da request (feita para o arquivo `check-email.php`) deve ser `true` or `false`.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203690/1267304).